# Creating a powershell counter that returns from a separate file

Tags: powershell, counter

I am baby-new to coding and yet I have been tasked with a problem that requires a piece of code. I need to have something count the number of times this script has run. Since it needs to stop it needs to save said counts elsewhere hence why I would assume it would need to go to a separate file. I tried to type out the steps in plain English to hope that someone can help me put it into PowerShell.

```
open a file
print number it has
look at the number
    if it is <=2
        than increase the number by 1 in file
            end
    if it is =3
        than wait 10 minutes
            change number to 1 in file
                end
```

Comment: have you tried using the help system to look up each step? or using your fave search engine with something like `powershell open file`? [*grin*]

Comment: I have. For many days now. I have been trying to google each piece and create a test for each line, but all I have been able to do so far is write something to a file and then echo it back. Even the next step of getting the output of said Get-Content as a variable has taken me the entire day and I have nothing to show for it. That is why I have come to my final desperate act of  begging for assistance from the internet.

Comment: Just use a log file that has one line, the script name and the run date and timestamp, which you later can tally up. Yet, to get assistance from the community SO has rules:    [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)    -    [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)    -    [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @MilkOverflow - the problem is that S-O is not a code writing service - it's a "help me with my code that doesn't work right" place. [*grin*] most folks here will _happily_ help if you show that you have tried. right now, you don't show any sign that you have actually tried anything. so .. most folks will just ignore your Question. ///// **_so, please, show in your Question what you have been able to do._**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this should do exactly what you asked for. But its terrible and Start-Sleep is the worst way to do it. You may want to look at [Register-ScheduledJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/register-scheduledjob?view=powershell-5.1)

```
$Filepath = "C:/myfile.txt"

$Counter = Get-Content -Path $Filepath

#To echo it to the command line
$Counter

If ($Counter -le 2){
    $NewCounter = $Counter + 1
    Set-Content -Path $Filepath -Value $NewCounter
    }

elseif ($Counter -ge 3) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
    $NewCounter = 1
    Set-Content -Path $Filepath -Value $NewCounter
    }
```

Comment: this mostly works. unfortunately it goes 1, 11, 111, 1111, etc. but I can work with that. I had to change the <-le 2> to <-le 11> and <-ge 3> to <-ge 111> to get it to work, but this worked! Thanks. You saved my butt. Also I understand it more now.